# What are the casual words that helps to express yourself in Internet chat

Tags: word-usage, internet

English is the second language for most of us. So when we chat in the internet, sometime our wordings looks more formal and not interesting. But I found when I chat with native English Guys, they uses some interesting(casual)  wordings to express their real feeling. So what are the such wordings do you uses in your internet chat. here are some i recognize.

- I'm going to leave - got to go (g2g).
- Well, that is an unfortunate situation - Oh man, that stinks

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Unhappily, this is a bit too much to be answered in our format, so I think it will be closed. But [*THIS*](http://www.internetslang.com/) site might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the internet jargon that I know :

ttyl : talk to you later ,
omg : oh my god ,
g2g : got to go

Also frequently smileys are used :

:) - happy face ,
:( - sad face , 
;) - winking

Words such as dude , man , yup , nopes are commonly used.